# Single Solrj call for adding and deleting docs

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solr4j

I am using `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.HttpSolrServer` for calling solr. 
For sequential delete and add operations , I am hitting solr like

```
        solr.addBeans(<solrDocs>);
        solr.deleteByQuery(<Query>)
        solr.commit();
```

Is there anyway, I can achieve same in one solr call, like solr.execute(addbean, deleteByQuery1)?

I know that multiple commands may be contained in one message as per [solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON). I what to know that how to achieve same in solrj and any other java library.

**What I want to achieve by this ?** 
Atomic opertion.

Lets have a case:There are two process(or thread) P1 and P2. Each perform Add(corresponding A1 and A2) and Delete(D1 and D2) operation. Let the sequence be like this :
D1 (Deletion of docs by process P1) 
D2 (Deletion of docs by process P2) 
A2 (Addition of docs by process P2) 
P2.commit  -> (This will make D1 commited in Solr too) 
A1 (Addition of docs by process P1) : Now even if it failed, **D1 is not going to rollback** (beacuse of P2.commit)

What I want is to rollback P1.D1

Comment: no, you couldn't do that. What's the point of do that? You want some kind of a batch processing?

Comment: @Mysterion, I have edited the question to explain what i want to achieve.